# Is it possible to programmatically remove cookies for a domain in Cocoa/iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cookies

Basically I make a request to a server using NSURLRequest, like: GET www.example.com/blah

The response from the server tells the browser to set some cookies. I need these cookies to make subsequent requests to www.example.com/blah2 and blah3, etc.

Once I have completed the series of sequential requests I need to rerun them, except I want to get fresh cookies from the server. Ideally, I'd want to delete all cookies on the example.com domain before rerunning the sequence of GETs.

What's the best way to do this in the Cocoa/iPhone SDK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into `NSHTTPCookieStorage`. It should be able to do everything you need.